# not able to call UDF in beamSql

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a below beamSql query :

```
PCollectionTuple query0 = PCollectionTuple.of(
            new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("temp2"), temp2).and(new TupleTag<BeamRecord>("temp3"), temp3)"));     
            PCollection<BeamRecord> rec_3 = query0.apply(
            BeamSql.queryMulti("SELECT a.*, \r\n" +
                    "(case \r\n" +
                    "when a.grp > 5 then 1 \r\n" +
                    "when b.grp > 5 then 1 \r\n" +
                    "else 0 end) as flag \r\n" +
                    "from temp2 a left join \r\n" +
                    "temp3 b on a.eventid = b.eventid and b.Weekint = c1(a.Weekint)").withUdf("c1", AddS.class));
```

In the above query I'm doing left join between tables temp2 and temp3 and in the ON condition I'm calling a UDF with the name 'AddS'.
In this UDF **AddS** , Weekint is taken as BigInt. The UDF is taking Weekint as input and converting it to date format then add 7 to it and return the value as BigInt. Below is the UDF :

```
public static class AddS implements BeamSqlUdf {                
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public static BigInteger eval(BigInteger input) throws ParseException{
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
         String strdate = input.toString();
            Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(strdate);
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  
             c.setTime(date1);
             c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
             String f =c.getTime().toString();
             BigInteger x = new BigInteger(f);   
                return (x);
              }
            }
```

I'm getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: No assign rules for OTHER defined
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeAssignmentRules.canCastFrom(SqlTypeAssignmentRules.java:326)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.type.SqlTypeUtil.canCastFrom(SqlTypeUtil.java:863)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil$4.test(SqlUtil.java:567)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil$4.test(SqlUtil.java:527)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.runtime.PredicateImpl.apply(PredicateImpl.java:36)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators$6.computeNext(Iterators.java:617)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:366)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:163)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.lookupSubjectRoutines(SqlUtil.java:438)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlUtil.lookupRoutine(SqlUtil.java:371)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlFunction.deriveType(SqlFunction.java:245)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlFunction.deriveType(SqlFunction.java:223)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl$DeriveTypeVisitor.visit(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5053)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl$DeriveTypeVisitor.visit(SqlValidatorImpl.java:5040)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.accept(SqlCall.java:137)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.deriveTypeImpl(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1588)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.deriveType(SqlValidatorImpl.java:1573)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlNode.validateExpr(SqlNode.java:225)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlOperator.validateCall(SqlOperator.java:407)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateCall(SqlValidatorImpl.java:4764)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.validate(SqlCall.java:114)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlNode.validateExpr(SqlNode.java:224)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlOperator.validateCall(SqlOperator.java:407)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateCall(SqlValidatorImpl.java:4764)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.SqlCall.validate(SqlCall.java:114)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateWhereOrOn(SqlValidatorImpl.java:3636)
at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.sql.repackaged.org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorImpl.validateJoin(SqlValidatorImpl.java:2988)
at
```

I'm not able to figure out whats causing this error , probably the UDF isn't created properly or it is not called properly ?
or If someone can explain me the cause of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UDF isn't created properly. Beam SQL doesn't support the Java BigInteger type internally. If your SQL datatype is BigInt, then you should use the java Long type instead.

(I have [opened an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4746) with Beam to make this error easier to understand.)

Comment: Thanks alot. I changed the corresponding java datatype to Long instead of BigInteger and it worked.